# Flask-wtforms: file not uploading

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, web-frameworks

I'm trying to upload a file using flask_wtforms. The html page gets opened and I can choose the file but nothing happens when I click submit. There is no validation error or any other error. I've tried searching through the docs for support to no help. Here is the code along with the relevant imports:

*routes.py*

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = OrderForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f = form.photo.data
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
    return render_template('upload.html', form = form)
```

*forms.py*

```
    photo =  FileField('Prescription', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['txt', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'], 'Images only!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Place order')
```

*config.py*

```
class Config(object):
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'D:\\projects\\project1\project1\\uploads'
```

*EDIT 1: added *upload.html* file*

*upload.html*

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    <p>
        {{ form.prescription() }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: A few things... 1) Have you run this in a debugger or put a print() stmt after your f =... line? Does f have a value? 2) Does this appear in your HTML: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">? 3) Did you see this in the docs...If you pass in the data explicitly, remember that request.form must be combined with request.files for the form to see the file data. -> form = PhotoForm(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form))) ?

Comment: @Ben Thank you so much for taking out the time to reply. As for 2, I've done that and 3 is not required because I'm using flask-wtforms not wtforms. The docs says so. But for clarity I'm editing my question to upload the html file too. I am a total beginner and I don't know how to do what you say in 1. Can you please help?

Comment: Sure! What environment are you programming in? You might want to download the free version of a product called PyCharm. It (as do all similar tools) has a tool that allows you to stop your program in the middle and look at the value of your variables at the point. For now, after the line "f = form.photo.data" put a new line, "print(str(f))". Then run your program. Your console / screen should show if there's anything in the variable f. That will tell you if it received anything to that point in your program. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll shift my editor to PyCharm. I added the print(str(f)) line and it's giving me the name of the file. However, the mistake I was doing was that I was rendering the template twice in my view. I changed the render_template inside the "if" conditional so that it redirects to a page. To be precise I changed ```return render_template('upload.html', form=form)``` to ```return redirect(url_for('orderplaced'))``` I still thank you a lot for the reply. I learnt how to debug if something goes wrong.

Comment: My pleasure! Best of luck!